# Finding the index number of normalizer of a non-normal subgroup when the index of subgroup is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $H$ is a non-normal subgroup of a group like $G$, where $[G:H]=p$ and $p$ is a prime(in other words $o(G)/o(H)=p$).
prove that $N(H)=H$. in other words $[G:N(H)]=p$.

appreciate it if you help me with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $H \subseteq N_G(H) \subseteq G$ and $|G:H|=|G:N_G(H)| \cdot|N_G(H):H|$. $H$ is normal iff $G=N_G(H)$.

Comment: Oh that works, thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome!